# Copy text in combo-box Java

Tags: java, swing, combobox, key-bindings

My requirement is that if user press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. The text in the combo-box will automatically be copied (without it being highlighted, the whole word would be copied). So if I go to another combo-box, I could paste it. I am new to java and don't have an idea how to it,

This is an illustration of the scenario requirement:

1. Cursor is at the first combo-box indicating that this is the current
   editable.

   [image]
2. User press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
3. User selects third combo-box (Cursor is at the third combo-box indicating that this is the current
   editable) then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
   [image]

So far I only have this

```
JTextComponent editor = (JTextComponent) combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    Action test = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //do function here
        }
    };

    editor.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK), "test");
    editor.getActionMap().put("test", test);
```

Comment: Is the text actually selected before pressing `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: No, don't use a KeyListener for this sort of thing. Instead search out the Key Bindings tutorial and use these instead.

Comment: @ScaryWombat nope, nothing is highlighted

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks, I changed my current code, how can I copy the text?

Comment: You're asking for information that takes up several tutorials, and rather than recreate the tutorials for you here, I urge you to seek them out and read them.

Comment: within the action listener you can get the source, the current JComboBox, from the ActionEvent's `getSource()` method, and then from that get its selected item.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I see, I forgot to put that I can already access it. It's working already. Thanks! Btw, does keybinding support Korean characters? I haven't seen any tutorials regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar:

I used the InputMap and ActionMap of the JComboBox itself, and used the InputMap condition of WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ComboCopy extends JPanel {
    private static final int COMBO_COUNT = 3;
    private static final String[] DATA = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
            "Thursday", "Friday"};
    private List<JComboBox<String>> combos = new ArrayList<>();

    public ComboCopy() {
        for (int i = 0; i < COMBO_COUNT; i++) {
            JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(DATA);
            setBindings(combo);
            combos.add(combo);
            add(combo);
        }
    }

    private void setBindings(final JComboBox<String> combo) {
        int condition = WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT;
        InputMap inputMap = combo.getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = combo.getActionMap();

        KeyStroke ctrlC = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        KeyStroke ctrlV = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);

        inputMap.put(ctrlC, ctrlC.toString());
        actionMap.put(ctrlC.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();
                if (text != null) {
                    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                    Transferable contents = new StringSelection(text);
                    clipboard.setContents(contents, null);
                }
            }
        });
        inputMap.put(ctrlV, ctrlV.toString());
        actionMap.put(ctrlV.toString(), new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
                if (contents != null && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
                    String text;
                    try {
                        text = (String) contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                        combo.setSelectedItem(text);
                    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ComboCopy mainPanel = new ComboCopy();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ComboCopy");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of other people who might encounter this weird requirement.

```
JTextComponent editor = (JTextComponent) combo.getEditor().getEditorComponent();

    Action copyAllText = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String item = combo.getEditor().getItem().toString().trim();
            StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(item);
            Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, null);
        }
    };

    editor.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK), "copyAllText");
    editor.getActionMap().put("copyAllText", copyAllText);
```